# Given a tower of extensions how to show that the degree of an extension is even?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Suppose $\Bbb{Q} \subseteq F \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ is a tower of
>   extensions and suppose that $i \in F$.
>
> If the extension $\Bbb{Q}
>  \subseteq F$ is finite, show that $[F : \Bbb{Q}]$ is even.

What I have attempted so far:

By the tower law we have

$$ [\Bbb{C} : \Bbb{Q}]= [\Bbb{C} : F][F : \Bbb{Q}]$$

Now $ [\Bbb{C} : \Bbb{Q}]=\infty$ and so since $[F : \Bbb{Q}]$ is finite we must have $[\Bbb{C} : F]=\infty$ now I don't know how to proceed any advice?

Comment: Hint: Since $i\in F$, $\mathbb Q(i)$ is a subextension of $F$

Comment: $\mathbb C$ has infinite dimension over $\mathbb Q$, and certainly $F$ can have, for example, degree $4$. The idea is to use the tower law on the extension $F/\mathbb Q(i)/\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Oh I think I see so $[F:\Bbb{Q}]=[F:\Bbb{Q}(i)][\Bbb{Q}(i):\Bbb{Q}]=2[F:\Bbb{Q}(i)]$ so clearly it is even. I would have never spotted to use tower law on the extension you give.